# What exactly is the information passing and Docker intermediate container creation during builds?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Dockerfile which I'm running locally:

```
FROM golang:alpine
COPY . /go/src/analytics
RUN cd /go/src/analytics  
RUN go clean
RUN go build
ENV PORT 8082
EXPOSE 8082
ENTRYPOINT analytics
```

The local folder contains these files: `Dockerfile`, `go.mod` and `main.go`.

When I run `docker-compose` I get:

```
Building analytics
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/8 : FROM golang:alpine
 ---> 7762f5dece68
Step 2/8 : COPY . /go/src/analytics
 ---> 8b943980fef8
Step 3/8 : RUN cd /go/src/analytics
 ---> Running in be8cc536c7af
Removing intermediate container be8cc536c7af
 ---> 6171b59a3b5e
Step 4/8 : RUN go clean
 ---> Running in f8528c5dc577
Removing intermediate container f8528c5dc577
 ---> c370fd1b7c04
Step 5/8 : RUN go install
 ---> Running in 540a67b77147
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
The command '/bin/sh -c go install' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'analytics' failed to build : Build failed
```

I have already seen [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787500/why-does-docker-create-containers-while-building-images) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604332/dockerfile-what-are-the-intermediate-containers-doing-exactly), but I still don't get it.

**Questions:**

1. With `COPY . /go/src/analytics`, I'm assuming that all the three files `Dockerfile`, `go.mod` and `main.go` get copied to an intermediate container `8b943980fef8`. When the next command `RUN` is executed, do the three files get copied into the next intermediate container `be8cc536c7af`?
2. From my understanding, a container has its processes and filesystem separate from other containers. So with each intermediate container being created, does the Docker build process actually spend time copying files and any other context to the next intermediate container or does it just keep note of all containers and have a common namespace for them?
3. Since I got the error `go.mod file not found in current directory`, I'm assuming either the file didn't get copied into the container or because the `clean`, `build` and run commands are all happening in different containers, so the run command isn't able to find any executable. What is actually happening?
4. In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68539261/what-are-the-sha256-repositories-when-deleting-a-docker-image), I asked about the extra Docker repositories. Are those repositories the intermediate repositories created during the Docker build? I understand the `8b943980fef8` ID's are actually short forms of the SHA256 ID's.
5. I know I could use `RUN cd /go/src/analytics && go clean && go install`, but then how do `COPY . /go/src/analytics` and `RUN cd /go/src/analytics` work when they are in two different intermediate containers?

Comment: This is a long question - but at least one obvious problem: You cannot `RUN cd` anything. You must either use `WORKDIR` or `RUN cd somewhere && do something` in the same step.

Comment: @DannyB: So the lines would be changed to `WORKDIR /go/src/analytics`, `COPY . .`, `RUN go clean && go install` in that order. Correct?

Comment: I had more to say, and wanted to respect StackOverflows "no discussions in comments" rule - so I posted an answer with hopefully *some* clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answers**:

> With COPY . /go/src/analytics, I'm assuming that all the three files Dockerfile, go.mod and main.go get copied to an intermediate container 8b943980fef8. When the next command RUN is executed, do the three files get copied into the next intermediate container be8cc536c7af?

Nyes. The next intermediate container already holds the three files, and the file system is inherited. Yes, it's like a copy, but Docker is not copying anything

> From my understanding, a container has its processes and filesystem separate from other containers. So with each intermediate container being created, does the Docker build process actually spend time copying files and any other context to the next intermediate container or does it just keep note of all containers and have a common namespace for them?

No, the Docker image system is a Merkle-tree based file system. For this, every new container **inherits** the single copy of the file system of the base image and whenever modifications occur Docker saves them into a new child node, by only computing (and physically writing) the differences between the **layers**

> Since I got the error go.mod file not found in current directory, I'm assuming either the file didn't get copied into the container or because the clean, build and run commands are all happening in different containers, so the run command isn't able to find any executable. What is actually happening?

You are missing the `WORKDIR` instruction. Either use `WORKDIR /go/src/analytics` or change the `RUN` commands to point to the directory `/go/src/analytics`. `WORKDIR` is a lot more *standard*. You'll say yourself in the next questions

> In a previous question, I asked about the extra Docker repositories. Are those repositories the intermediate repositories created during the Docker build? **I understand the 8b943980fef8 ID's are actually short forms of the SHA256 ID's**.

You understand correctly. Yet, there's a lot of simplification.

> I know I could use RUN cd /go/src/analytics && go clean && go install, but then how do COPY . /go/src/analytics and RUN cd /go/src/analytics work when they are in two different intermediate containers?

As I said above, the intermediate containers inherit the file system, and this especially because the build steps run in sequence and not in parallel. So you can use that instruction but it's not the cleanest. Yet, it works.

**Explanation**:

What the instruction does is to **run** (isn't it named RUN for a reason?) the commands on top of the previous build step

```
FROM golang:alpine
COPY . /go/src/analytics
RUN cd /go/src/analytics && go clean && go build
```

`COPY` runs on top of `FROM`. That means you are going to copy files into a container made of Go runtime. This creates an intermediate layer `7762f5dece68` which contains **both** Go from previous step and your files

`RUN` runs on top of the above, which is `7762f5dece68`. That image, as I said earlier, contains both Go and your source code

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I can answer everything, but at least to point out a few observations.

#### Steps that alter the file stsrem

Each of the `FROM`, `COPY`, `ADD`, and `RUN` steps (perhaps some others) end up with new updates to the file system of the image.

This is one of the reasons `RUN cd somewhere`, as a standalone step, does not have any effect, since it changes nothing in the file system.

The structure of the file system is what passes down to the next layers.

#### `WORKDIR`

The correct way to specify a working directory in a Dockerfile, us by using the `WORKDIR` directive. This will change the working directory from this point downward, and it can be specified multiple times throughout the file.

#### Docker layers

The reason it is usually recommended to combine several `RUN` actions together, especially if they belong in the same logical group, is to a) ensure they are executed together, and b) to reduce the number of intermediate layers.

#### Corrected Dockerfile

A corrected version of your Dockerfile will look like this:

```
FROM golang:alpine
WORKDIR /go/src/analytics  

COPY . .
RUN go clean && go build

ENV PORT 8082
EXPOSE 8082
ENTRYPOINT analytics
```

#### Docker inspection

As it seems you are curious about the inner workings (or not?) of the docker building process - you might want to try some tools for docker inspection, for example [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) - this might also help with your other question.

#### Rule of thumb

A good rule of thumb that helped me when I started building Dockerfiles is this: Think of each `ADD`, `COPY` or `RUN` step as if you  are starting a new shell session, in the image that you have built up to this point. At the end, only the files you generate matter, as they will be the base for subsequent steps.

Comment: With pleasure :)